# Rubymine :: Git is not working, getting fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: rubymine

Rubymine was working fine. I was able to perform all kind of git related operation using rubymine seamlessly. But suddenly its not working. When I want to pull its says:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

It also fails for all other read/write > operation.

But git is working fine in my machine. I mean I can push/pull using command line. But now working with rubymine.

I am using Mac.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First make sure that you can use git from command line. If you can then,

```
Go to settings -> Version Control -> Git
Select "SSH executable" -> Native
```

And then restart Rubymine.

Comment: This totally worked...thanks for saving me a lot of trouble!! I'd love it if you could post some info on *why* it works -- is there a way to add an ssh key to RubyMine to get the built-in SSH option to work?

Comment: Saved me! Any idea WHY? This is so odd.

Comment: not working for me as private key with passphrase.... Any solution please? Thanks in advance...

Comment: This change didn't help me, but by adding C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin to my system path did the trick.  Giving credit to this blog post: http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/need-an-ssh-client-on-windows-dont-use-putty-or-cygwinuse-git

Answer (score 0):

Did you init a local git repository, into which this remote is supposed to be added?

Does your local directory have a .git folder?

Try git init...

**Step 1 - Attempt adding you public key to Heroku**

heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

**Step 2 - Generate a new set of SSH keys, then attempt the first step again**

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

**Step 3 - Verify and/or modify your config file**

vim ~/.ssh/config

```
Host heroku.com
Hostname heroku.com 
Port 22 
IdentitiesOnly yes 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa    <--- Should be your public SSH key
TCPKeepAlive yes 
User jsmith@gmail.com
```

**Step 4 - Remove the heroku remote from git, the recreate the connection**

Add the remote via heroku create will only be an option for new repositories. Be sure to delete your old repo that you originally attempted to create

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ git heroku create
```

**Step 5: Reinstall Heroku Toolkit**

http://hayley.ws/2010/12/04/getting-jekyll-running.html

Comment: I can push/pull using command line, not working with rubymine